# Maya Python Delete children from a duplicated joint

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to delete the children from a joint that I duplicated in maya with python and is not working. What am I'm missing ?

```
import maya.cmds as mc
mc.duplicate('spine02_Joint',n='spineGrpJnt')
mc.parent('spineGrpJnt',w=True)
mc.select('spineGrpJnt')
childJnts = mc.listRelatives(ad=True)
mc.delete(childJnts)
```

From what I'm understanding this should delete everything in the childJnts but it gives me the error : ' More than one object matches name:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drastically simplify your code by using the `parentOnly` kwarg in the `duplicate` command so that it duplicates the node you specify without any of its children

```
import maya.cmds as mc

new_jnt = mc.duplicate('spine02_Joint', n='spineGrpJnt', parentOnly=True)[0]
mc.parent(new_jnt, w=True)
```

Just another minor note: most (if not all) maya commands allow you to pass in an object to modify and also return the name of the "new" object.  By storing it in a variable, you can then pass the variable around instead of the string for the object name.  This is especially helpful if an object already exists by that name and maya names it with a 1 at the end (ex: 'my_object1').  That way you're not having to manage selections and worry about names which could lead to commands operating on the wrong objects - and that can be very difficult to track bugs...

So you could write your original code like this:

```
import maya.cmds as mc

new_jnt = mc.duplicate('spine02_Joint',n='spineGrpJnt')[0]
mc.parent(new_jnt, w=True)
childJnts = mc.listRelatives(new_jnt, ad=True, pa=True)
mc.delete(childJnts)
```

Comment: Why the [0] first index of array ? The duplication gives you an array ?

Comment: true, the duplicate command does return a list, but in this case, it's a list of 1 item (the single duplicated joint).  So, rather than putting `new_jnt[0]` everywhere you use it later, it's a little easier to capture the first item into the variable.  Also, since I didn't name the variable 'new_jnts' it makes more sense for it to only be a single item instead of a list for readability.  And often, you're feeding the return data as a single item into the next command anyway (like parent and listRelatives on the next 2 lines)

Comment: It basically boils down to how you're going to use the data the commands return - if I'm only interested in one item (or I already know it's only going to give me a single item in a list), I get the 0 index; if I may be getting more items, then I don't - hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out .
The code should be :

```
import maya.cmds as mc
mc.duplicate('spine02_Joint',n='spineGrpJnt')
mc.parent('spineGrpJnt',w=True)
mc.select('spineGrpJnt')
childJnts = mc.listRelatives(ad=True,pa=True)
mc.delete(childJnts)
```

Added the pa=True to the listRelatives gives me what I want .